# Why is the "webform submission updated" hook not using the correct data?

Tags: 7, hooks, webforms

Created a function in respond to `hook_webform_submission_update` to generate a FillPdf.

```
function my_module_webform_submission_update($node, $submission) {

    if ($submission->nid == 43) {

        $uuid = ($submission->data['975'][0]);
        $sid = ($submission->sid);

        $f = "./sites/default/files/docs/mdx_lh_" . $uuid . "_" . $sid . ".pdf";

        if (file_exists($f)) unlink($f);

        $wf = array(array("nid" => 43, "sid" => $sid));

        fillpdf_merge_pdf(326,NULL,$wf); 
    }
}
```

When the event is triggered, after pressing the save button, the FillPdf uses the old data.
  Going over the webform a second time without changing anything, just clicking the save button, the FillPdf uses the correct data.

I thought the `hook_webform_submission_presave` was to change data (if needed) but it seems the event `hook_webform_submission_update` is triggered before data is actually saved.

Is there a way to force data save before calling `fillpdf_merge_pdf`, or is there another event to use?

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason querying the database give the correct data and yet the FillPdf sevice uses the older one, we moved the routine to the point where the results are showed, where its activated with a button. This option works fine.